# Prove $Y_S$ is integrable if $Y$ is a bounded supermartingale and $S$ is an a.s. finite stopping time.

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, stopping-times

Let $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \{\mathscr{F_n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}, \mathbb{P})$ be a filtered probability space, and let $Y = ({Y_n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a/an $(\{\mathscr{F_n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}, \mathbb{P})$-supermartingale.

> Prove $Y_S$ is integrable if $Y$ is a bounded supermartingale and $S$ is an a.s. finite stopping time.

So far all I was able to show is that $Y_{S \wedge n}$ is integrable and $E[Y_S] \le E[Y_0]$.

Hints pls?

Comment: Choose $C>0$ such that $|Y_k| \leq C$ for all $k$. Then $$|Y_{S}(\omega)| = |Y_{S(\omega)}(\omega)| \leq C;$$ hence $Y_S \in L^1$.

Comment: @saz Thanks, but where is the assumption of $S < \infty$ a.s. used? What if $S = \infty$ ?

Comment: $Y_{S(\omega)}$ doesn't make sense if $S(\omega) = \infty$.

Comment: @saz $= \lim_{n \to \infty} Y_n$ ? Well if the limit exists I guess?

Comment: Under this (rather strict) assumptions the limit exists, but in general it doesn't. If we define $Y_{\infty}(\omega) := \lim_{n \to \infty} Y_n(\omega)$, then the statement holds also true if $S$ is not necessarily a.s. finite.

Comment: @saz I'm not sure I follow. I guess S can be $\infty$ if the limit exists, but how do we know the limit exists? Or are you saying we need to assume the limit exists before we drop the finite a.s. assumption?

Comment: Since $(Y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is assumed to be a **bounded** supermartingale, the limit exists. However, for a general stochastic process $(Y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ we do not know that the limit $\lim_n Y_n$ exists and that's why it is usually assumed that $S<\infty$ a.s.

Comment: @saz That is very strange. Okay, thanks. Post as answer?

Comment: @saz Is that really what bounded means? I think that is [uniform boundedness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness). If merely bounded, we have $C = C_k$, I think?

Comment: You wrote "a bounded supermartingale" ... Usually, this means that the process is bounded, i.e. the constant does not depend on $k$.

Comment: @saz So Math1000 is [wrong](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1551258/is-x-t-bounded-if-x-n-is-bounded#comment3158964_1551258)?

Comment: No, he isn't. For ambigious definitions there is no such thing as "wrong". But why are you keeping to ask these things? If this is homework, then ask your lecturer what (s)he means by a bounded process.

Comment: @saz This is not homework. I got this from Probability w/ Martingales. Now that my other question has been marked a dupe, do you mind justifying why we can say $Y_S$ is (uniformly) bounded if $Y_n$ is (uniformly) bounded?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by uniform boundedness of $Y_S$?

Comment: @saz $\exists C>0$ such that $|Y_k| \leq C$ for all $k$, at least that is the impression I got from Wiki and Math1000. If bounded, C may depend on k

Comment: Yes, that's uniform boundedness of the process $Y$; if you want to call it like that. But what do you meanby uniform boundedness of $Y_S$? (see your penultimate comment)

Comment: @saz Oh mea culpa. Is $Y_S$ bounded if $Y_n$ is uniformly bounded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we have already discussed this depends on your definition of a "bounded process".

**If** you mean that $Y$ is (uniformly) bounded, i.e. there exists $C>0$ such that $|Y_n| \leq C$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, i.e. $$|Y_n(\omega)| \leq C \qquad \text{for all $\omega \in \Omega$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$} \tag{1},$$ then the claim does hold true. Indeed: Fix $\omega \in \Omega$. Then $$|Y_{S}(\omega)| \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} |Y_{S(\omega)}(\omega)| \stackrel{(1)}{\leq} C.$$ This shows that $Y_S$ is bounded; hence in particular integrable.

**If** you mean that each $Y_n$ is bounded, i.e. there exists $C_n>0$ such that $|Y_n| \leq C_n$, then the claim does, in general, not hold true as the following counterexample shows.

Consider $\Omega := \mathbb{N}$ endowed with the counting measure

$$\mathbb{P}(d\omega) := c \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{n^2} \delta_n(d\omega)$$

where the constant $c$ is chosen such that $\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{N})=1$. Define a (non-negative) random variable by

$$X(\omega) := \frac{1}{\omega}, \qquad \omega \in \Omega.$$

Then $Y_k :=-k^2 X$ is a supermartingale (see the lemma below), each $Y_k$ is bounded and

$$S := \inf\{k \in \mathbb{N}; Y_k = -k\}$$

defines a (finite) stopping time. By the very definition of $(Y_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $S$, we have $$\{S=k\} = \left\{\omega \in \Omega; -k^2 \frac{1}{\omega} = -k \right\} = \{k\}.$$

Consequently,

$$\mathbb{E}(|Y_S|) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |k| \cdot \mathbb{P}(S=k) =c \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k}{k^2} = \infty,$$

i.e. $Y_S$ is not integrable.

---

The following lemma (which we used for the above counterexample) is not difficult to prove:

**Lemma:** Let $X \geq 0$ be an integrable random variable on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$ and $(a_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathbb{R} \backslash \{0\}$ a sequence of non-increasing real numbers. Then $Y_k := a_k X$ defines a supermartingale (with respect to the canonical filtration).

Comment: Doesn't seem to follow easily to me :(

Comment: @BCLC Not within 10 minutes after reading the answer? Well, then just think a little longer about it.... and if you still don't understand it, then tell me what exactly you do not understand.

Comment: Is that supposed to prove the first claim about uniform boundedness? That is what I want to understand. Pls see answer I posted. I want to understand why exactly the first $\to$ holds. Intuitively it makes sense because S is ultimately going to be some natural number once an omega is put in there, but I have difficulty proving it rigorously

Comment: @BCLC No, the counterexample is supposed to show that $Y_S$ is, in general, **not** integrable if $(Y_n)_n$ is not uniformly bounded. Because of your answer, I thought that you already know how to prove that the claim holds if uniform boundedness is satisfied.

Comment: I dont know which is why I asked another question w/c is now a dupe :|

Comment: @BCLC See my (edited) answer. (And honestly: Why do you answer your question if you don't understand your own answer? Doesn't make sense to me.)

Comment: Thanks saz, but how is this? I wanted to try a different approach. $$|X_T| = |X_1 1_{T=1} + X_2 1_{T=2} + ...| $$

$$ \le |X_1| 1_{T=1} + |X_2| 1_{T=2} + ... $$

$$\le C 1_{T=1} + C 1_{T=2} + ... $$

$$\le C [1_{T=1} + 1_{T=2} + ...] $$

$$\le C [1] = C \ QED $$

Comment: @BCLC Yeah, that's also okay...