# Should monotone convergence theorem say uniformly bounded?

Tags: calculus, probability, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

saz pointed out to me the difference between [bounded and uniformly bounded](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1526098):

> $Y$ is **uniformly bounded**:
>
> there exists $C>0$ such that $|Y_n| \leq C$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, i.e. $$|Y_n| \leq C \qquad \text{for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$}$$

---

> $Y_n$ is **bounded**:
>
> there exists $C_n>0$ such that $|Y_n| \leq C_n$

---

The context was in random variables, but I guess it also holds for real numbers.

---

The [monotone convergence theorem for real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Theorem) uses bounded. Should it be uniformly bounded?

Wiki describes a [bounded sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_function). So actually such sequence is uniformly bounded?

Comment: Yes. It should be read as uniformly bounded. Example: $Y_n = n$, $C_n = n+1$.

Comment: However, I think, usually, what you call uniformly bounded is called bounded (?)

Comment: @MatiasHeikkilä thanks ^-^ so calculus textbooks are just simplifying language?

Comment: For a sequence of real (or complex) numbers, bounded is the correct term. For a sequence of functions, the notions of bounded and uniformly bounded are distinct. Each individual function may be bounded without the sequence being uniformly bounded.

Comment: @carmichael561 Oh wait I think I get it. It actually doesn't make sense to talk about a bounded but not uniformly bounded sequence of real (or complex) numbers so let's just use 'bounded' for 'uniformly bounded' and then discard the idea of bounded but not uniformly bounded sequences?

Comment: @BCLC: That's right, uniformly bounded is redundant for a sequence of real numbers.

Comment: @carmichael561 Post as answer?

Comment: @BCLC: I posted it.

Comment: @carmichael561 Thanks ^-^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a sequence of real (or complex) numbers, bounded is the correct term. For a sequence of functions, the notions of bounded and uniformly bounded are distinct. Each individual function may be bounded without the sequence being uniformly bounded.